# React native textinput numeric issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Need help, i was just placed `material-ui` textfield in react native and I have set:

`keyboardType: {numeric}`

Its works fine but when I entered 30,000 it's showing `NaN` I want to restrict comma(,) and dot(.) in keyboard. When I type amount it will calculate and show result in text.

```
<TextField 
     onChange={(event)=>this.handle(event.nativeEvent.text)}
     label='Amount'
     value={this.state.amount}
     keyboardType = 'numeric'
     enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}>
</TextField>
```

Answer (score 1):

The displayed value will always be `this.state.amount`. So if you change the value to discard everything but numerical digits, there will only be digits on the screen.

One extra thing you could do is change the keyboardType to 'number-pad', but I don't know how cross-device that is.

Use the following...

```
<TextField 
     onChange={(event)=>this.handleChange(event.nativeEvent.text)}
     label='Amount'
     value={this.state.amount}
     keyboardType = 'number-pad'
     enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}>
</TextField>  

handleChange(event) {

    this.setState({amount: event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Since you are using the [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), means storing the field value in state variable, So to restrict the user from entering input `,` and `.`, put the check inside `onChange` method, if entered value is integer then only update the state value otherwise not.

Like this:

```
<TextField 
    onChange={event => this.handle(event.nativeEvent.text)}
    label='Amount'
    value={this.state.amount}
    keyboardType = 'numeric'
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}>
</TextField> 

handle(value){
    if(/^\d+$/.test(value))
        this.setState({amount: value})
}
```

Comment: thnks but if there is any possible to disable it?

Comment: it won't display in a screen at all have to disable.

Comment: don't have idea about that :), but i think that is not possible.